# let domain user make local backup on a local computer

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy

I have windows 2008R2.
I create a GPO for local adminitrator. So that every domain user I add there , they are also local administrator on the PC.
Now I'd like to do the same but with more restrict operation, I creare another GPO and add these as member:

- BackupOperators
- Network configuration Operators

But once I log in I'm not able to perform backup or change IP . Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a TON of trouble by granting users those 3 roles. It would be less risky if you were to simply create a scheduled task that runs a backup on each machine. You can use Group Policy to create and deploy that scheduled task to each of them.